# how to display categories in data class with retrofit2 - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

i am trying to display data from API using retrofit2 in koltin

but the API shows that there is categoryId before the data i am calling as showing below:

```
  [
   {
    "categoryId": 0,
    "categoryName": "string",
    "ilmFinders": [
    {
    "eventId": 0,
    "eventName": "string",
    "eventLocation": "string",
    "eventPhoto": {},
    "eventDescription": "string",
    "eventDate": "string",
    "eventLink": "string",
    "isFavourite": {}
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
```

i tried to call only (eventName, eventPhoto, eventLink) in my data class as showing below:

```
data class IimfinderData(

val eventLink: String,
val eventPhoto: String,
val eventName: String

)
```

API interface:

```
        interface finderService {
        @GET(" ")
        fun getServices() : Call<List<IimfinderData>>
        companion object Factory {
        fun create(): finderService {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("PRIVATE URL")
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(finderService::class.java)
        }
        }
        }
```

Adapter:

```
class IimfinderAdapter(var countryList: List<IimfinderData>, var activity: MainActivity): RecyclerView.Adapter<IimfinderAdapter.ViewHolder>(){
lateinit var context: Context
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IimfinderAdapter.ViewHolder {
    context = parent.context!!
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item2, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countryList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IimfinderAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.eventName.text = countryList[position].eventName
    holder.eventLink.text = countryList[position].eventLink




    Picasso.with(activity)
        .load(countryList[position].eventPhoto)
        .error(R.drawable.qiblacompass)
        .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
        .into(holder.eventPhoto)




}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val eventName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_tv2)
    val eventLink: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_url2)
    val eventPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_tv2)

}

}
```

after i run the application, it shows that the data are null

do i need to call "categoryId"?

and if yes, how can i call 2 arrays in the same data class?

the Adapter and the code in my activity is correct because i tested it with another API

so what am i doing wrong here?

------------------------------- Solution ------------------------

refer to the answer down and i have to change how i call the data from the adapter

instead of this:

```
holder.eventName.text = countryList[position].eventName
```

do this:

```
holder.eventName.text = countryList[position].ilmFinders[position].eventName
```

Comment: You are not parsing the response correctly. "eventName" is outside "ilmFinders" array. And also "eventPhoto" is not a string but JsonObject

Comment: @BhargavThanki thank you but can you be more clear about it? because i am still new to kotlin, 
i have called different data classes in the same way and it is working but this one it gives me "null"

Comment: Would you show your `service` interface code?

Comment: @liveAnyway i have added the interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Check point

- data that you want is in List of List

  - jsonArray > jsonArray > IimfinderDataJson
    `IimfinderData` by List
- `eventPhoto` is Object, not String

try this code

`Call<List<IimfinderData>>` -> `Call<List<IlmFinders>>`

```
fun getServices() : Call<List<IlmFinders>>
```

and

```
data class IlmFinders(
    @SerializedName("ilmFinders")
    val ilmFinders: List<IimfinderData>
)

data class IimfinderData(
    @SerializedName("eventLink")
    val eventLink: String,
    @SerializedName("eventPhoto")
    val eventPhoto: Any,
    @SerializedName("eventName")
    val eventName: String
)
```

if your data class properties name is same with json element, you don't need `@SerializedName`

Comment: thank you, but when i change the Call<List<IimfinderData>> -> Call<List<IlmFinders>> i can't call data from the adapter

Comment: yes i tried, when i update the code as you mentioned i get an error in the adapter in line "countryList[position].eventName" that it can't find "eventName" and same goes to other data

Comment: I mean, update your code on your post that you tried.

Comment: i just had to call the right position of the data from the adapter, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to access jsonArry in API response you can do as below:

Create data class for "IimfinderData" with serialization as:

```
data class ResponseData(
@SerializedName("name")
val userName: String,
@SerializedName("age")
val userAge: Integer,
@SerializedName("date_of_birth")
val userDOB: String)
```

than use this class as the list of data in data class as:

```
data class Response(
@SerializedName("userData")
val ilmFinders: List<ResponseData>)
```

access this data class with function as :

```
fun getServices() : Call<List<Response>>
```

Make sure to use **@SerializedName** Annotation if you are not using same name as response data

Hope this will solve your problem !!